# AFTSurvivalRegression LBFGS Error Objective Poorly Behaved

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, survival-analysis

I'm getting the following messages from the following calls:

```
import pyspark.ml.regression as sparkreg
...
aftsr = sparkreg.AFTSurvivalRegression(labelCol="time", censorCol="event", featuresCol="features", maxIter=1000)
aftsr = aftsr.fit(sdf)

2018-04-17 14:20:42 ERROR StrongWolfeLineSearch:27 - Encountered bad values in function evaluation. Decreasing step size to 0.5
2018-04-17 14:20:43 ERROR StrongWolfeLineSearch:27 - Encountered bad values in function evaluation. Decreasing step size to 0.25
2018-04-17 14:20:43 ERROR LBFGS:27 - Failure! Resetting history: breeze.optimize.FirstOrderException: Line search zoom failed
2018-04-17 14:20:43 ERROR LBFGS:27 - Failure! Resetting history: breeze.optimize.FirstOrderException: Line search failed
2018-04-17 14:20:43 ERROR LBFGS:27 - Failure again! Giving up and returning. Maybe the objective is just poorly behaved?
```

And then it returns "bad" values for scale and intercept. Is there a way to avoid this? Can I provide initial estimates to `.fit`? Unfortunately, I can't share the data. This happens in one problem instance, but not in others.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug ([SPARK-21523](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21523), [SPARK-21919](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21919), [SPARK-21919](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21919)) caused by another bug in the Breeze library ([Fix strong wolfe line search init value bug #651](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/pull/651)).

Should be fixed in Spark 2.2.1 and 2.3 .

Comment: This is my pyspark version: `pyspark=2.3.0=py36_0`. Should I still encounter this problem?

Comment: I installed pyspark through Anaconda.